# Using web3-react connectors is deprecated and may lead to unexpected behavior

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web3-react, usedapp

I am currently implementing a wallet connection using react and useDapp provider.
For wallet connection, I installed @web3-react.
So injected-connector and wallet-connector of @web3-react are what I chose.

The problem is the warning of useEthers.ts of @usedapp/core.

> 'Using web3-react connectors is deprecated and may lead to unexpected
> behavior.'

I can not understand its behavior and what I should prefer to use for a web3 connection.
Here's what I have done so far.

walletmodal.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import Backdrop from "@material-ui/core/Backdrop";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";
import Button from "./button";
import { useEthers } from "@usedapp/core";

import MetamaskImage from "../img/wallet/metamask.svg";
import WalletconnectImage from "../img/wallet/walletconnect.svg";
import CoinbaseImage from "../img/wallet/coinbasewallet.svg";

import "./walletmodal.scss";

import { ChainId } from "@usedapp/core";
import { InjectedConnector } from "@web3-react/injected-connector";
import { WalletConnectConnector } from "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector";

const injected = new InjectedConnector({
  supportedChainIds: [ChainId.Polygon],
});

const walletconnect = new WalletConnectConnector({
  rpc: {
    [ChainId.Polygon]: "https://polygon-rpc.com/",
  },
  bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org",
  qrcode: true,
  supportedChainIds: [ChainId.Mainnet, ChainId.Rinkeby],
});

const activateInjectedProvider = (providerName: string) => {
  const { ethereum } = window;

  if (!ethereum?.providers) {
    return undefined;
  }

  let provider;
  switch (providerName) {
    case "coinbase":
      provider = ethereum.providers.find(
        ({ isCoinbaseWallet }: { isCoinbaseWallet: string }) => isCoinbaseWallet
      );
      break;
    case "metamask":
      provider = ethereum.providers.find(
        ({ isMetaMask }: { isMetaMask: string }) => isMetaMask
      );
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  if (provider) {
    ethereum.setSelectedProvider(provider);
  }
};
const WalletConnectionModal = ({
  open,
  onClose,
}: {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const { account, activate, deactivate, connector, chainId, switchNetwork } =
    useEthers();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (account && chainId !== 137) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        deactivate();
      }, 100);
      switchNetwork(137);
    } else if (!account && chainId === 137) {
      if (value === "metamask" || value === "coinbase") activate(injected);
      if (value === "walletconnect") activate(walletconnect);
    }
  }, [account, value, chainId, deactivate, activate, switchNetwork]);

  return (
    <Modal
      aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
      aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
      className="modal"
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      closeAfterTransition
      BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
      BackdropProps={{
        timeout: 500,
      }}
    >
      <Fade in={open}>
        <div className="paper">
          <div className="content">
            <Button
              secondary
              customClass={
                "button " + account && connector === injected && "selected"
              }
              onClick={async () => {
                activateInjectedProvider("metamask");
                await activate(injected);
                setValue("metamask");
                onClose();
              }}
              fullWidth
            >
              <img src={MetamaskImage} alt="metamask" />
              <span className="inner">
                Metamask
                <small>Connect to your MetaMask Wallet</small>
              </span>
            </Button>

            <Button
              secondary
              customClass={
                "button " + account && connector === walletconnect && "selected"
              }
              onClick={async () => {
                await activate(walletconnect);
                setValue("walletconnect");
                onClose();
              }}
              fullWidth
            >
              <img src={WalletconnectImage} alt="walletconnect" />
              <span className="inner">
                WalletConnect
                <small>Scan with WalletConnect to connect</small>
              </span>
            </Button>
            <Button
              customClass={
                "button " + account && connector === injected && "selected"
              }
              onClick={async () => {
                activateInjectedProvider("coinbase");
                await activate(injected);
                setValue("coinbase");
                onClose();
              }}
              fullWidth
            >
              <img src={CoinbaseImage} alt="coinbase" />
              <span className="inner">
                Coinbase
                <small>Connect to your Coinbase Wallet</small>
              </span>
            </Button>
            {account && (
              <Button
                secondary
                customClass="disconnect"
                onClick={() => {
                  deactivate();
                  setValue("");
                }}
              >
                Disconnect
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fade>
    </Modal>
  );
};
export default WalletConnectionModal;
```

button.tsx

```
import clsx from "clsx";
import * as React from "react";
import BaseButton from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import BeatLoader from "react-spinners/BeatLoader";

import "./button.scss";

interface ButtonProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  disabled?: boolean;
  customClass: any;
  secondary?: boolean;
  loading?: boolean;
  onClick: () => void;
  fullWidth?: boolean;
}

const Button = ({
  children,
  disabled,
  customClass,
  secondary,
  loading,
  onClick,
  fullWidth,
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const classes = clsx(
    "button",
    { disabled: disabled },
    { secondary: secondary },
    customClass
  );

  return (
    <BaseButton className={classes} onClick={onClick} fullWidth={fullWidth}>
      {loading ? <BeatLoader color="#fff" loading={true} size={8} /> : children}
    </BaseButton>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

I only implemented metamask, coinbase, and walletconnect.
I want to know why this warning is happening and why there is a warning message in useEthers.ts of @usedapp/core.